# Waiting until a modal is closed in a for loop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have'a for loop and at each iteration, I'm planning to open a modal(**I'm using bootstrap** **2.3.2**). But there is a problem, I need to wait until the current modal is closed. So here is my code:

```
for(i in connections){

var sourceId=connections[i].sourceId;
var sourceResultSet;
sourceResultSet=findResultSet(sourceId,blocks);
$('#match-body').append($('<p id="filterInfo">'+sourceResultSet+'</p>'));
$('#input-output-match').modal('show');
// now here, until the current modal is closed, the code should wait  and then it need to continue to iteration.
}
```

and this is my html part:

```
<div id="input-output-match" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> × </button>
          <h3 id="myModalLabel">Source Entity Name -> Target Entity Name</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id='match-body'>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Finish</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't stop that loop. Whole approach needs restructuring

Comment: @charlietfl do you have any idea? I'm stuck with that

Comment: Use modal hide event and a counter to check where you are in the process. Trigger modal update within that event

Comment: @charlietfl I'm new with web design and bootstrap could you provide at least template  so that I could understand?

Comment: Do you really need a series of modals? Seems unusual

Comment: @charlietfl I need to take an input from the user and each iteration,  and based on the user's selection I'll provide different options every time. So I think modal would be fine, what could I use rather than modal ?